# Typescript union type array `a[] | b[]` is not `reduce`able, but `map`able

Tags: typescript, lambda, type-inference, union-types

I'm trying to `reduce` over a union of array-types: `foo[] | bar[]`.
With `map` it works as expected and I get an element of `foo|bar` in the lamda, but it does not work with `reduce`.
I get the error, that 'the expression is not callable, because the signatures are not compatible'.

Maybe [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33591) is related, but that was in TS 3.6 days, and I'm using 4.5.
Is there a (neat) way around this?

I have a Typescript Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&jsx=0&ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtjAvDA2gXRgQwjAggJ30wE8AeMAVzgCMBTfGAHxmnwEswBzAPgG4BYAFBwAdPloATCsFoAKWWygBKJNxiKlA4SLiYADvI2r1yrUNCRYcAExJUGbHkIlyVOvjXMCRMqw48tGzFJaTkFZWMNQOtgqRlDCMQ1RSwcTDBiTRgYAHocmDAQWFoAN1owGAB3RQALGABydOJ6gFoAG0waCUwhPJgAFRq2HFoADz1xCAg2cHUcQthgTDaO6jbaEV78gFFMYDq4Whp6GBAAMxgoGtoYCjAZiqhiPRv60gB5AFkASX7%207YAImoRCD6jAao5ppwwJgoBRJgAaGDUCiwQpgG7nS41EAQG5QmFwyZYcQwUBwPSwthrG7VK4wWh7OpFa74TbCGK6AzhFRJExZPqVGrEGASEC0HBcqogfAAa2x5RgAH4hFsWJ1abVLhQ9OsIOZwNB4ABmOwoACMSPNDhwKEox3wSPt7gwzBQfi4aECxp0%20gSvOSpiEcB94jiYSMfKiQiAA)

```js
const m = [] as Array<number | string>;
m.reduce((it) => it); // ok
m.map((it) => it); // ok

const m2 = [] as Array<number> | Array<string>;
m2.reduce((it) => it);
m2.reduce((it) => it as any);  // not even with 'any'-lambda
// This expression is not callable.
// Each member of the union type '<OMITTED> ...' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
m2.map((it) => it); // why does `map` work then ?

// same with tuples
const m3 = [1, 1] as [number, number] | [string];
m3.map((it) => it);
m3.reduce((it) => it); // same error
```

Comment: Shouldn't `reduce` take a function of *two* arguments?

Comment: yes typically and semantically, but not necessarily (as example 1 shows). The error is the same, hence the cast to `any`, and see the Playground example.

Comment: The currently open issue about this is https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44373 , although it's marked as "needs investigation".  Improvements have been made for this calling unions of functions in TS3.3 ( https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36390 ) and TS4.2 ( https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31023 ) so maybe this will eventually be addressed?  Until then you can safely widen `A[] | B[]` to `readonly (A | B)[]` and call `reduce()` on that, like [this](//tsplay.dev/NdjjvW).  Shall I write up an answer describing this or are you looking for something else?

Comment: I don't know where the `readonly` is coming from (and if its necessary, doesn't seem like it, the ts-dev also works w/o). However, looking at the `tuple`-example, I'd loose the information, that `[string, number]` is not possible (before) but after. I guess I need to wait for those issues to be addressed, then. And until then use one array of a union type instead. You can write that as an answer and I'd accept it (for the time being at least, 'fingers crossed')

Comment: plus most importantly, it would add `undefined` to the type i am iterating over, which then inside the lambda would require even more checks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to jcalz comment, this is a known restriction of TS, but there's a workaround that you shift the type predicate job to generic inference instead of a whole type predicate of which array type is

```js
function map<T extends number | string>(arr: T[]) {
    return arr.map(v => v); // no error
}

function reduce<T extends number | string>(arr: T[]) {
    return arr.reduce(it => it); // no error
    // return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + (typeof cur === "number" ? cur : cur.length), 0); // no error either, with some practical logic
}
```

Comment: Someone needs to compile a gigantic list of all the Typescript nonsense and put it in one place, because no one can convince me this is good or intuitive language design. Thanks for your comment, this indeed worked.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to jcalz comment I found the following.

[Typescript Definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-array/index.d.ts)

The function signature for map is

```
export function map<T, U>(iterable: Iterable<T>, mapper: (value: T, index: number, iterable: Iterable<T>) => U): U[];
```

It has a different return type U then it's input T.

*One* of the function signatures for reduce is

```
export function reduce<T>(
   iterable: Iterable<T>,
    reducer: (previousValue: T, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, iterable: Iterable<T>) => T,
initialValue?: T
): T;
```

It has the same return type as it's input (T). The trouble comes when assigning the type back unto itself. Typescript doesn't (and shouldn't) know which type to use.

One solution is to type check before using reduce, with a type guard like so,

```
const isNumberArray = (arr: unknown[]): arr is number[] => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const element = arr[i]

      if (typeof element !== 'number') {
          return false
      }
  }

  return true
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&jsx=0#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%20MDWn6LEN7UgAeQAsgBJfX6j0AETUIkzexgtWhVs4YEwlwtABoYNQKLBAmAQ4G6iAHiw2AWi1daLzxF0QHA9EW2C6Q3K6r1vQrxbV6G7hGCdPp2SpOSZBXqgrUXBIQO34PpZVk-EGJzcAPyTQR6iCawfyoMUPR5CDAyzwADMkIAjGW3xhoShDvQy3%20%20AYMwKBolwaBaHAz6zgYtILlyphCFBlKsjSRiLgyQhAA)

Comment: Thanks, that solution could work, is big and bulky plus, most importantly, I don't care in that context, if it is an array of either type. I only care, *that* it is an array, and this should be `reduce`able...

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more use